# How to change priority of WTForms validators?

Tags: validation, flask-wtforms, wtforms

**tl;dr:** I need to change the order in which WTForms validators validate the user input. How do I do that?

**Details:**

Flask code:

```
class SampleForm(Form):
    user_email = user_email_field
...
@api.route('/sample-route')
class ClassName(Resource):
    @api.expect(sample_payload)
    @api.marshal_with(sample_response)
    def post(self):
        form = SampleForm(formdata=MultiDict(api.payload))
        if not form.validate():
            return {"form_errors": form.errors}, 400
        ...
```

WTForms validation field:

```
user_email_field = EmailField('Email Address',[
    validators.InputRequired(Errors.REQUIRED_FIELD),
    validators.Length(min=5, max=256),
    validators.Email(Errors.INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS),
])
```

Problem is, `user_email` is checked by validators in the wrong order. I send a request with the following body:

```
{
  "user_email": ""
}
```

I get this response:

```
{
  "form_errors": {
    "user_email": [
      "'' is too short"
    ]
  }
}
```

As you see, despite being 2nd in the list of validators, `validators.Length()` kicks in before everything else.

If I comment it out in the validation field like that:

```
user_email_field = EmailField('Email Address',[
    validators.InputRequired(Errors.REQUIRED_FIELD),
    # validators.Length(min=5, max=256),
    validators.Email(Errors.INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS),
])
```

then the exact same request will yield a desired response:

```
{
  "errors": null,
  "success": null,
  "form_errors": {
    "user_email": [
      "REQUIRED_FIELD"
    ]
  }
}
```

However, this is not a working solution because, of course, then eMail won't be checked for its length.

**Question:**

How do I change the priority of these validators? How do I make WTForms always check the user input with `validators.InputRequired()` FIRST and with `validators.Length()` SECOND and not the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question:
You can use custom validators for that purpose. Then you can change the order of validation by `if, elif, else` logic within.

```
class Test(Form):
    test_field = StringField('Test_Field')
    submit = SubmitField()

    def validate_test_field(self, test_field):
        try:
            if len(test_field.data) == 0:
                raise wtforms.validators.ValidationError('Input is required for this field!')
            elif len(test_field.data) not in range(5, 257):
                raise wtforms.validators.ValidationError(f'Error in input length.')
        except TypeError as e:
            raise wtforms.validators.ValidationError('Input is required for this field!')
```

Check the documentation for custom validators [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/validators/)